# Criar Dto pelo Construtor com um parametro List de uma entidade Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, query, spring, hql

Eu tenho uma **@Query** do Spring, que realiza uma consulta ao banco por uma Entidade, para criar alguns Objetos **DTO**. E as propriedades desse objeto DTO, eu passo via Construtor, mas eu precisava passar como parâmetro no Construtor um **List** que tem na Entidade.

```
public OperacaoDTO(List<Staging> stagings, BigDecimal valor) {
        this.stagings = stagings;
        this.valor = valor;
    }
```

meu **@Query**

```
@Query("SELECT NEW br.com.teste.OperacaoDTO(operacao.stagings, operacao.valor) FROM Operacao operacao")
    List<OperacaoDto> findAll();
```

O problema que ele reclama dizendo que não tem um construtor apropriado no OperacaoDTO.
Existe algum modo de esse **List** da Entidade e passar no Construtor? porque eu vou realizar alguns tratamento nessa **List**

Comment: Você poderia fornecer o erro completo? Como está o mapeamento da entidade `Operacao`?

Answer (score 1):

Você deve cria um construtor da seguinte forma para o objeto

```
OperacaoDTO(operacao.stagings, operacao.valor)
```

Os tipos devem ser iguais ao Objeto, por exemplo:
se valor for Double e stagings for String ficaria assim

```
public OperacaoDTO(String stagings, Double valor){
  this.stagings=stagings;
  this.valor=valor;
}
```

Você criou um construtor com uma lista

```
List<Staging> stagings, BigDecimal valor,
```

Tua query não retorna isso e sim um objeto com dois atributos.

- Mais, se **OperacaoDTO** for do tipo `@Entity` deve ter o construtor vazio também, requisito do hibernate